# How do I delete data using from two database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete data from two tables at once. I have articles in one spreadsheet, and I have page permissions in the other spreadsheet that clearly specify who gets to the article and who doesn't. However, if I want to delete a given article, I am unable to put together the sql code to delete the permissions based on the url article. I tried this without any result

```
DELETE * FROM article_permission
JOIN article ON article.article_id = article_permission.article_id
WHERE article.url = 'kjebgkwb'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE ap.*, a.* 
FROM article_permission ap
JOIN article a ON a.article_id = ap.article_id
WHERE a.url = 'kjebgkwb'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE p, a 
FROM article_permission p
JOIN article a ON a.article_id = p.article_id
WHERE a.url = 'kjebgkwb'
```

It is even easier if you set your table relation to `ON DELETE CASCADE` then you only need to delete from the `article` table and the DB does the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.id = 'idnumber'
```

Or

You have to run two different delete query or You have to set foreign key on the other table so it will automatically delete records with this id.